# Em tempo de execução, o ID do Formulário asp.net webforms se altera?

Tags: c#, webforms

Em tempo de execução, o ID do Formulário asp.net webforms se altera, veja que eu tenho na minha máquina o Id do componente.

Exemplo local:

```
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server"  ID="MenuSelecionado" value="processo"/>
```

Após execução fica assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MenuSelecionado" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuSelecionado" value="processo">
```

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de manter o ID ou usar outra propriedade
no lugar dele.

Answer (score 1):

Tem sim, você pode pode usar o `ClientIDMode`

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server"  ID="MenuSelecionado" value="processo" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

É possível ver mais sobre ele na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Outra alternativa:

Mantenha o controle assim:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="MenuSelecionado" Value="processo" />
```

E no Page_Load:

```
MenuSelecionado.ID = "MenuSelecionado";
```

O problema dessa forma é que ele irá adicionar o texto "MainContent" antes, ficando assim o elemento

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$Bla" id="MainContent_MenuSelecionado" value="processo" type="hidden">
```

<sub>Vou fazer alguns testes se acho outra forma</sub>

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mais não deu certo,O tipo 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' não tem uma propriedade pública denominada 'ClientIDMode'.

Comment: Estranho não funcionar, talvez seja versão, fiz um teste aqui e foi. De todo modo adicionei uma outra alternativa

Comment: Não da para usar o ClientIDMode="Static", não funciona